# Flutter i18n shortcut

Tags: flutter, internationalization

I'm trying to make a function that get my i18n string by passing variable.

```
String getStringLanguage(context, String key) {
  dynamic translation = AppLocalizations.of(context);
  String tmp = key.toString();
  return translation.key;
}
```

but I have this error

> Class 'AppLocalizationsFr' has no instance getter 'key'.
> Receiver: Instance of 'AppLocalizationsFr'
> Tried calling: key

I understand why I have this error, but is it possible to force flutter to use my key variable, instead of searching the **key** constant ?

this is a small part of my AppLocalizations class

```
abstract class AppLocalizations {
  String get email;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try...

1- Import the library

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

2- Use the function to get the value

```
Intl.message(translation.key)
```